# Command not running from inside shell script

Tags: ssh, freebsd, scp

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh

scp /conf/acme/* gentooserver:/etc/ssl/apache2/
scp /conf/acme/* octopi:/etc/ssl/
```

When I execute it, I get output indicating at least the first command executes. (Plus the script has worked before when it was just the first line). But if I look in octopi:/etc/ssl/, the files aren't there.

If I just execute `scp /conf/acme/* octopi:/etc/ssl/` on the command line, the files copy fine.

Why does this command not work from inside a shell script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, so I logged back in, and the file lacked the second line, as though I never added it? Even though I opened and closed vi several times during the last session and the line was there.

I don't know how to use vi, so I just installed nano and edited the file properly. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting as answer since I can't comment.*

Add `-v` on your `scp` invocations to see verbose output that might indicate the issue. You might also try `rsync -v ...` if the output from `scp -v ...` isn't helpful.